# replace list of sentence to the text

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace the text if it contains the sentences from a `list1`.

I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
text = "what a lovely car it is , i love it by the way it looks and the color is so good . i am feeling very happy after ) seeing it"
list1 = ['lovely car it is', 'color is so good','happy after )']

#code i tried
for i in list1:
  if i in text:
    text.replace(i,"")

#wrong output:
'what a lovely car it is , i love it by the way it looks and the color is so good. i am feeling very happy after seeing it'
```

Expected output:

```
'what a , i love it by the way it looks and the . i am feeling very seeing it'
```

Comment: text =text.replace(i,"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python [strings are immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html); the `str.replace()` method doesn't alter the *existing* string, but rather, it returns a *new* string based on the existing string.

So simply replace `text.replace(i,"")` with `text = text.replace(i,"")`. Observe:

```
text = "what a lovely car it is , i love it by the way it looks and the color is so good . i am feeling very happy after ) seeing it"
list1 = ['lovely car it is', 'color is so good','happy after )']

for i in list1:
  if i in text:
    text = text.replace(i, "")

print(text)
```

Output:

```
what a  , i love it by the way it looks and the  . i am feeling very  seeing it
```

Answer (score 0):

replace will create a new string so use.

```
text = text.replace(i,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, the only error is the statement: , `text.replace()` This function does not make changes to the original variable, it returns an object that is a copy of the original object, so you need to assign it to text.
Code:

```
text = "what a lovely car it is , i love it by the way it looks and the color is so good . i am feeling very happy after ) seeing it"
list1 = ['lovely car it is', 'color is so good','happy after )']

#code i tried
for i in list1:
    if i in text:
        text = text.replace(i,"")
```